# Compute drag force on a mesh in SU2 CFD (beginner)

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I am a complete beginner in computational fluid dynamics. I have a 3D mesh in Blender representing the object I would like to do my tests on. I can export it in (I think) any useful format for 3D. I would like to know where I can start to make this kind of simulation with SU2 CFD:

- External flow
- Air at standard conditions
- Air flows against my mesh at some speed (say, 10 m/s)
- I would like to know what the drag force on my object will be

Is it possible in some easy way? I tried to have a look around but couldn't find any tutorial or example.

Thank you

Comment: This is a question best asked of the SU2 developers and/or the corresponding mailing lists.